# How to update a value to a random column in MySQL in Java

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have a table as 'tbl_password' as below

[image]

I want update the value of password randomly from password1-password5 for particular user. So every user will have its real password in different positions.

**This is expected result.
"Pass" written in Red color must be updated.**
[image]

Waiting for your answers. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Will you update all five password columns or randomly one password column?

Comment: one random column value for one user n so on

Comment: show your expected out put

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this.

```
$all_columns=array("password1","password2","password3","password4","password4");
$random_keys=array_rand($all_columns,1);
$column_name =  $all_columns[$random_keys];
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET $column_name= 'somevalue'";
```

For Java Try like this.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Simple {

       public static void main(String args[]){

       String[] all_columns= {"password1","password2","password3","password4","password4"};
       int idx = new Random().nextInt(all_columns.length);
       String random = (all_columns[idx]);
       String sql = "UPDATE tablename SET "+random+" = 'somevalue'";
       //Use update query here
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me for java, it seems your code is for php

Comment: Yes it is for PHP. I ll update you answer with java.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl_password 
set CONCAT('password',FLOOR( 1 + RAND() *5 ))='$password' 
where user='$user';
```